# $_GET to store a dynamic session

Tags: php, html, session

I'm a PHP noob and I need some help if you can.
I have a little website similar to a survey in witch i click on a link and in the next page I have get the previous variable and store it through all the survey.

In the first page I have 5 buttons to choose:

```html
<a href="question-2.php?q1=1" class="sfondo-form w-inline-block"></a>
<a href="question-2.php?q1=2" class="sfondo-form w-inline-block"></a>
<a href="question-2.php?q1=3" class="sfondo-form w-inline-block"></a>
<a href="question-2.php?q1=4" class="sfondo-form w-inline-block"></a>
<a href="question-2.php?q1=5" class="sfondo-form w-inline-block"></a>
```

in the second page I use $_GET to have the first variable

```html
<?php
// Starting session
session_start();


if (isset($_GET['q1'])){
    $question_1 = $_GET['q1'];
    $_SESSION['q1'] = $question_1;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $_SESSION['q1'];
}
else{
    header('location: index.php');
    exit();
}


?>
```

My problem is that is someone change the url (question-2.php?q1=ANYTHING-ELSE)
I need to redirect them to the home page.
Basically I need to have an `If` statement in witch I only `echo` the five results of the 5 `href`

So I can have one session `$_SESSION['q1']` with dynamic content but restricted to this five.

I know it's wrong but i need to restrict the get to this:

```
if (isset($_GET['q1']) && (($_GET['q1'])= '1' or '2' or '3' or '4' or '5'){}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `if (isset($_GET['q1'])` that should be throwing you a parse error.

Comment: `header('index.php');` does nothing.

Comment: Hi @FunkFortyNiner I have fixed the header, but I don't know how to fix the parse error

Comment: the parse error can be fixed by adding another (closing) bracket `if (isset($_GET['q1']))`.

Comment: yes sorry, I have missed a ).. sorry and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do here is have an array of allowed values and check if **q1** value is one of the values in the given array:

```
<?php
// Starting session
session_start();

$allowed = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
if (isset($_GET['q1'])) {
    $question = (int) $_GET['q1'];
    if(in_array($question, $allowed, true)){
        $_SESSION['q1'] = $question;
        echo '<br>';
        echo $_SESSION['q1'];
    } else {
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
} else {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Nota: `if (isset($_GET['q1']){` is a parse error that the OP did and you copied it without fixing it/adding the missing bracket. Edit: Along with `header('index.php');` which doesn't do anything.

Comment: I probably miss something but it's not working. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for noticing it. I will update my answer accordingly